# Rebuilding Qt application does not change the string

Tags: qt, qt5

Kindly consider me as a fresher in Qt. I have written the following code for the button click event.

```
void dbCheck ()
{
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");

    QString dbPath(QDir::home().path());

    dbPath.append("/Desktop/jk/sample.sqlite");
    qDebug () <<"Path Name is "<<dbPath;
    .......
}
```

And after some time, I have changed the following line into

```
dbPath.append("/Desktop/jk/Newsample.sqlite");
```

When I ran the code,  still it prints the previous path i.e. `sample.sqlite`.

I cleaned the project, and rebuild the same, but no use, still I'm getting the same result. Really weird.

Did I miss something here? How can I rectify this problem? Anything related to do with cache? Kindly advise.

Comment: Interesting case, sounds weird. Just wondering.. try to change the qDebug() input to something else. Hard to believe that after recompiling the execution of qDebug will get updated and your dbPath qString will remain `...sample.sqlite`

Answer (score 1):

Be careful about mixing in-source builds and "shadow builds". You get in-source build if you go to the source directory, and run `qmake` and `make`. On the other hand, Qt Creator by default uses separate build dir, AKA "shadow building", and you can of course do that yourself too. In practice this is done with `qmake` by creating build dir as *sibling* of source dir, going there and doing `qmake ../myproject` to generate makefiles in the shadow build dir.

Now the thing is, *make* program does not really have this concept of separate build dir, and if you have performed in-source build, then those built files are accessible to *make* too. Then when you think you're doing shadow build, *make* finds those built files under source directory and uses those instead of creating new ones.

In case this is the problem, **following should help**:

Go to the source dir at Qt SDK command prompt, and run

```
make clean distclean
```

Note: order is important, `distclean` will remove any makefiles too so it must be done last. Also replace `make` with `nmake` or `mingw32-make` or whatever you actually use. If that command does not find a makefile, then you probably have not run `qmake` there and issue is something else, but you can verify this by running `qmake` to generate the makefiles, and `make clean distclean` will work.

Alternative to remove extra files, if you use version control (and have not accidentally checked in generated files...) is to use the version control tool to remove all extra files from the version-controlled directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please, recheck your environment: do you really clears all? Insure, that you have no `*.o`, `moc_*.cpp`, `ui_*.h` from previous builds. Try to delete `.user` file and reconfigure your project to make builds to different folder.

Also, you can use concatenations of strings this way:

```
QString dbPath = QString("%1%2")
        .arg( QDir::home().path() )
        .arg( "/Desktop/jk/Newsample.sqlite" ) );
```

Offtop, but don't forget about **native separators** (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#separator and http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#toNativeSeparators) - if you write crossplatform software.